# Username for Facebook app profile page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

We have a bare bones "app" on Facebook, mostly so we can allow users to login to our site with FB. We also include a Like button on our site; right now the Like button points to our app profile page, where we occasionally post updates for our users.

https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=190439350983878

Our app profile page has a couple dozen Likes now, so we were hoping to be able to give the page a short user name like http://www.facebook.com/blahblah.

Is there a way to get a user name for our app? (I know it's possible to claim an URL on apps.facebook.com if we implement a Canvas page, but we don't have a Canvas app and don't see why we would.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visit https://www.facebook.com/username/ and choose your app's profile page in the drop down list.

Comment: "The page you requested was not found." There's no drop down.

Comment: @Dan For real? Here is Facebook's help page for usernames and how to claim them for pages. https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=897

Comment: Ah, I mistyped it! :-p